# Compare multiple data with if statement

Tags: c

how to compare multiple data in c ?

a program that will compare some user input and it will give the higest number and a lowest number

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    float rice , oil, suger, salt;
    float higest_price, lowest_price;

    printf("Enter the price of rice :\n");
    scanf("%f", &rice);
    printf("Enter the price of oil :\n");
    scanf("%f", &oil);
    printf("Enter the price of suger :\n");
    scanf("%f", &suger);
    printf("Enter the price of salt :\n");
    scanf("%f", &salt);

    if( rice < oil ){
        printf( "Oil is the higest price");
```

and from here i'm stuck!!!!
i don't know how to compare multiple data rice, oil, suger, salt

Comment: Read about `if...else`, and nesting of them.

Comment: If you have 4 numbers in front of you, how do you determine which is the largest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the array if you have not determined number of items to compare. You need also to know the name of the product:

```
typedef struct product
{
    char *name;
    float price;
}product;

product *largest(product *pr, size_t size)
{
    size_t maxIndex = 0;

    for(size_t index = 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if(pr[maxIndex].price < pr[index].price) maxIndex = index;
    }
    return pr + maxIndex;
}

int main(void)
{
    product pr[] = {
        {.name = "rice", .price = 5.5},
        {.name = "oil", .price = 1.5},
        {.name = "meat", .price = 7.5},
        {.name = "coce", .price = .75},
        };

    product *maxPrice = largest(pr, sizeof(pr) / sizeof(pr[0]));
    printf("%s %f\n", maxPrice -> name, maxPrice -> price);        
}
```

If you have fixed number of products you can use the ternary operator and macro definitions:

```
#define LARGEST2(p1, p2) ((p1) -> price > (p2) -> price ? (p2) : (p2))

int main(void)
{
    product pr[] = {
        {.name = "rice", .price = 5.5},
        {.name = "oil", .price = 1.5},
        {.name = "meat", .price = 7.5},
        {.name = "coce", .price = .75},
        };

    product *maxPrice = LARGEST2(LARGEST2(LARGEST2(pr, pr + 1), pr + 2), pr + 3);
    printf("%s %f\n", maxPrice -> name, maxPrice -> price);        
}
```

Comment: Any comment. What is wron with it?

Comment: Not my downvote, but recommending macros isn't a vote-winner.   **Style guide:** the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `maxPrice -> price` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `maxPrice->price`.

Comment: This answer is completely inappropriate for the knowledge level displayed in the question. When a student is just dealing with stringing together multiple `if` statements, it is not time to introduce arrays, structures, pointers, pointer arithmetic, named initializers, loops, or abstracted types. Code without explanation is usually a bad answer, egregiously so in this case. Further, `size_t` was used without explaining the necessary header, so attempting to use it will likely cause the student grief. And the program was changed not to read input with no explanation why.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I am newbe - only 40y programming as a day time job. I do not like this style as it IMO me more difficult to read.  Use spaces. BTW I added macros after it was DV-ted

Comment: I don't agree with all the style points of K&R, but I do agree with them on the lack space around the dot and arrow operators.  IMO, it makes your code look like a newbie's code, regardless of how long you've been programming.  However, if you insist, you can use it; the compiler won't mind.  That's why it is a 'style guide', not a 'style rule'.  And when you show that style to newbies and I spot it, I will usually comment that it is not idiomatic C.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int rice, oil, suger, salt;
    printf("Enter the price of rice: ");
    scanf("%d", &rice);
    printf("Enter the price of oil: ");
    scanf("%d", &oil);
    printf("Enter the price of suger: ");
    scanf("%d", &suger);
    printf("Enter the price of salt: ");
    scanf("%d", &salt);

    int largest = rice;
    int smallest = rice;

    if (oil > largest)
        largest = oil;
    if (suger > largest)
        largest = suger;
    if (salt > largest)
        largest = salt;

    if (oil < smallest)
        smallest = oil;
    if (suger < smallest)
        smallest = suger;
    if (salt < smallest)
        smallest = salt;

    printf("The Highest price is: %d\n", largest);
    printf("The lowest price is: %d\n", smallest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if he has 6 products?

Comment: How do you keep track of which product has the highest price, and which has the lowest?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**